# `require': cannot load such file -- paperclip/matchers (LoadError)

Tags: rspec, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, shoulda

I am using rails 5.1.1 & ruby 2.3.1

When i execute rspec i get following error

> `require': cannot load such file -- paperclip/matchers (LoadError)

Gemfile:

`gem "rspec-rails", '>= 3.6.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'`

I have included following in spec_helper.rb

```
require "paperclip/matchers"

config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
```

It seems like rspec did not get particular file related to paperclip for loading from rbenv gems folder.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your actual Gemfile has more entries. If nothing else, you probably have a gem server at/near the top:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

It looks as if the paperclip gem isn't a dependency for the other gems you listed:

```
$ bundle show paperclip
Could not find gem 'paperclip' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

So you might also want to add a line such as:

```
gem 'paperclip'
```

Then run `bundle install` and `bundle show paperclip`. If you still have problems, it might be you haven't installed bundler to using rbenv:

```
$ type bundle
bundle is hashed (/usr/local/bin/bundle)

$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.15.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.15.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.15.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

$ rbenv rehash

$ type bundle
bundle is ~/.rbenv/shims/bundle
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I alraedy have paperclip in my gemfile. I solved this issue by moving below 2 lines 

require "paperclip/matchers"
config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers

in rails_helper.rb